# Methods for analyzing food diary (time series CSV) to correlate foods to symptoms

Tags: python, time-series

## Background

The doctor recommended that I keep a food diary to try and figure out what foods are correlated to the symptoms I experience. However, they didn't have a recommendation for a method to analyze the collected data (apparently normal people don't do that!) ... so I figured, I can do statistics using python, right?

While I'm very familiar with python, unfortunately my statistics background is weak. As a starting point, I would like to know which foods are more correlated with which symptoms. Knowing what statistical method(s) to use to analyze this type of data would be a great starting point, python code would be even better.

## The data

I have transcribed my food diary into CSV similar to this form:

```
time,event
2018-07-12 16:30:00,food1
2018-07-12 16:35:00,food2
2018-07-12 17:00:00,symptom1
2018-07-12 17:05:00,symptom2
2018-07-12 18:10:00,food1
... etc, etc
```

It was trivial to load the data into jupyter+pandas+matplotlib and make scatterplots showing the data (which is cool, but not super helpful yet). I've been reading about various ways to one could analyze time series data, but a lot of that doesn't quite fit what I'm trying to do.

### My specific question

- Given data of the form shown above, how does one determine that particular named items are correlated with other named items? For example, "86% of the time food1 occurs 90 minutes before symptom1"

A subproblem: My google searches for time series data analysis seems to yield answers that all involve numbers, whereas this data is just a list of things and isn't very numerical (other than that it's a time series). If I load the data into pandas and call `data.corr()`, it gives me an empty dataframe. How does one typically overcome that?

Comment: @toros91 I edited the question to only ask a specific question. What needs to be changed to remove the hold? Thanks!